# Can we use one ViewPager adapter for multiple activities?

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have lot of activities in my app and each activity uses it's own ViewPager Adapter class.
Now I want to see if there's a possibility of using one ViewPager Adapter for all activities, just like a function where we can pass variables and get the desired outcome. If it is possible, could you provide me some code references?

Answer (score 0):

yes, create different objects for different ativities.Pass adequate parameters based on needs.

Comment: I'll try and come back with my tests and issues. Hopefully I can get better solution here.